# Как добавить дополнительное поле пользователю в личный кабинет на MODX?

Tags: modx, login

уважаемые знатоки Modx. Подскажите, как добавить дополнительное поле (файл) для пользователя на modx? Личный кабинет создан с помощью плагина LOGIN. Необходимо сделать так, чтобы в админке главный администратор мог добавлять пользователю PDF документ и чтобы он выводился в личном кабинете ссылкой. Доступ к этому документу имел бы только этот конкретный пользователь. Очень поможете, если знаете ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Вот полезные статьи, которые помогут создать такое поле:

- https://rtfm.modx.com/current/en/extending-modx/custom-users
- https://modx.com/blog/understanding-user-extended-fields
- https://docs.modx.com/3.x/en/extras/login/login.tutorials/extended-user-profiles

> Доступ к этому документу имел бы только этот конкретный пользователь

Каждый пользователь будет видеть в своем личном кабинете только свой документ,при наличии